# Read angular change in phone through accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer

Given that I can read the effects of gravity on my device on three axes, I'm looking for some math that will get me a more logical view of what's happening to the device in my hands. I want to create a two dimensional control based on tilting the device forward and back, and tilting the device to the right and left.

The seemingly complex part is that I'd like to have the controls behave in a predictable way regardless of the starting position that the device happened to be in when starting the controls. For instance, if the user is in bed holding the phone upside down above their head, everything should still work the same from the user's perspective even though the numbers coming off of the accelerometer will be entirely different. I can envision some sort of transformation that would yield numbers that look like the device is starting off on a flat table, given the actual state of the device when the controls start to be used.